# Validating the date formats using the variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code. I have got a problem with setting up the date formats. I'm using the value `int(next_day) + 1` so I could add the day to the next day date. Example: from this `01/07/2017` to this `02/07/2017` and so on.

Here is what I use:

```
if day_date == 1:
   if half_hour == "12:00AM":
      print "you are in the epg_time_1 in day 1 at 12am area...................."
      epg_time_1_days = int(next_day) + 1
      epg_time_1_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_1_months = str(today_month)
      epg_time_1_year = str(today_year)
      epg_time_2_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_2_months = str(epg_time_1_months)
      epg_time_2_year = str(epg_time_1_year)
      epg_time_3_days = int(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_3_days = str(epg_time_3_days)
      epg_time_3_months = str(epg_time_2_months)
      epg_time_3_year = str(epg_time_2_year)
      elif one_hour == "12:00AM":
      print "you are in the epg_time_2 in day 1 at 12am area...................."
      epg_time_1_days = int(next_day)
      epg_time_1_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_1_months = str(today_month)
      epg_time_1_year = str(today_year)
      epg_time_2_days = int(epg_time_1_days) + 1
      epg_time_2_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_2_months = str(epg_time_1_months)
      epg_time_2_year = str(epg_time_1_year)
      epg_time_3_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_3_months = str(epg_time_2_months)
      epg_time_3_year = str(epg_time_2_year)
   else:
      print "you are in the epg_time_3 in day 1 at 12am area...................."
      epg_time_1_days = int(next_day)
      epg_time_1_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_1_months = str(today_month)
      epg_time_1_year = str(today_year)
      epg_time_2_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_2_months = str(epg_time_1_months)
      epg_time_2_year = str(epg_time_1_year)
      epg_time_3_days = int(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_3_days = str(epg_time_3_days)
      epg_time_3_months = str(epg_time_2_months)
      epg_time_3_year = str(epg_time_2_year)
   elif day_date == 2:
      print "you are in the day 2 area...................."
      epg_time_1_days = int(next_day)
      epg_time_1_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_1_months = str(today_month)
      epg_time_1_year = str(today_year)
      epg_time_2_days = int(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_2_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_2_months = str(epg_time_1_months)
      epg_time_2_year = str(epg_time_1_year)
      epg_time_3_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_3_months = str(epg_time_2_months)
      epg_time_3_year = str(epg_time_2_year)
   elif day_date == 3:
      print "you are in the day 3 area...................."
      epg_time_1_days = int(next_day)
      epg_time_1_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_1_months = str(today_month)
      epg_time_1_year = str(today_year)
      epg_time_2_days = int(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_2_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_2_months = str(epg_time_1_months)
      epg_time_2_year = str(epg_time_1_year)
      epg_time_3_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_3_months = str(epg_time_2_months)
      epg_time_3_year = str(epg_time_2_year)
   elif day_date == 4:
      print "you are in the day 4 area...................."
      epg_time_1_days = int(next_day)
      epg_time_1_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_1_months = str(today_month)
      epg_time_1_year = str(today_year)
      epg_time_2_days = int(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_2_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_2_months = str(epg_time_1_months)
      epg_time_2_year = str(epg_time_1_year)
      epg_time_3_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_3_months = str(epg_time_2_months)
      epg_time_3_year = str(epg_time_2_year)
   elif day_date == 5:
      print "you are in the day 5 area...................."
      epg_time_1_days = int(next_day)
      epg_time_1_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_1_months = str(today_month)
      epg_time_1_year = str(today_year)
      epg_time_2_days = int(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_2_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_2_months = str(epg_time_1_months)
      epg_time_2_year = str(epg_time_1_year)
      epg_time_3_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_3_months = str(epg_time_2_months)
      epg_time_3_year = str(epg_time_2_year)
   elif day_date == 6:
      print "you are in the day 6 area...................."
      epg_time_1_days = int(next_day)
      epg_time_1_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_1_months = str(today_month)
      epg_time_1_year = str(today_year)
      epg_time_2_days = int(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_2_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_2_months = str(epg_time_1_months)
      epg_time_2_year = str(epg_time_1_year)
      epg_time_3_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_3_months = str(epg_time_2_months)
      epg_time_3_year = str(epg_time_2_year)
   else:
      print "you are in the pm else area...................."
      epg_time_1_days = int(today_day) + 1
      epg_time_1_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_1_months = str(today_month)
      epg_time_1_year = str(today_year)
      epg_time_2_days = str(epg_time_1_days)
      epg_time_2_months = str(epg_time_1_months)
      epg_time_2_year = str(epg_time_1_year)
      epg_time_3_days = str(epg_time_2_days)
      epg_time_3_months = str(epg_time_2_months)
      epg_time_3_year = str(epg_time_2_year)
   half_hour_date = str(epg_time_1_days + "/" + epg_time_1_months + "/" + epg_time_1_year + " " + half_hour)
   one_hour_date = str(epg_time_2_days + "/" + epg_time_2_months + "/" + epg_time_2_year + " " + one_hour)
   one_hour_half_date = str(epg_time_3_days + "/" + epg_time_3_months + "/" + epg_time_3_year + " " + one_hour_half)
```

There is a problem with my code, when my date format show as `30/07/2017` it will add it to `31/07/2017` and `32/07/2017` for those variables `epg_time_1`, `epg_time_2` and `epg_time_3`.

What I'm expecting to do is I want to set up the date formats `30/07/2017`, `01/08/2017` and `02/08/2017` by using the variables `epg_time_1`, `epg_time_2` and `epg_time_3`, but I have got no idea how to do this.

Can you please show me an example of what I could use the best way forward to set up the date format for those variables?

EDIT: Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
if epg_time_1_months == 1:
    if epg_time_1_days == 31:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 2



elif epg_time_1_months == 2:
    if epg_time_1_days == 28:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 3


elif epg_time_1_months == 3:
    if epg_time_1_days == 31:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 4


elif epg_time_1_months == 4:
    if epg_time_1_days == 30:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 5




elif epg_time_1_months == 5:
    if epg_time_1_days == 31:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 6



elif epg_time_1_months == 6:
    if epg_time_1_days == 30:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 7



elif epg_time_1_months == 7:
    if epg_time_1_days == 31:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 8


elif epg_time_1_months == 8:
    if epg_time_1_days == 31:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 9


elif epg_time_1_months == 9:
    if epg_time_1_days == 30:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 10



elif epg_time_1_months == 10:
    if epg_time_1_days == 31:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 11


elif epg_time_1_months == 11:
    if epg_time_1_days == 30:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 12



elif epg_time_1_months == 12:
    if epg_time_1_days == 31:
       epg_time_1_days = 01
       epg_time_1_months = 1
```

Comment: Your indentation is messed up. Is it because of copy-paste? or is it like this in your file?

Comment: @nutmeg64 No I did not messed up. I wrote it myself when used the media application as I'm setting the date formats when I getting the strings from the objects, example: `12:00AM`.

Comment: If you could show me an example of how I could setting up the date formats to add it to each day until it get to `30` then add next month and set the day date to `01` instead of `31` better than what I wrote then it would be great.

Comment: As i have said before, your code is not indented correctly. since Python is all about indentation, please correct your code. Also please make your code Complete. There are some variables that is not clear to me where you initialize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try and code the logical around dates yourself .... use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html%20datetime)  module from the python standard library. Dates are  complex and fiddly with lots of corner cases like leap years to deal with. Save yourself a stack of work and use an existing trusted library.

I'm not a 100% sure of your use case but bellow is a example function that does the equivalent of your "next_day"  use case, you can make it more concise but I've broken it down and commented it heavily to aide understanding:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta


def get_future_date(date_string, days_in_future, date_format='%d/%m/%Y'):
    intial_date_time  = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format) # parse the string into a datetime object
    date_only = intial_date_time.date()  #  remove time component so  you have a date object
    future_date = date_only + timedelta(days=days_in_future) # add a time delta to get a future date
    return future_date.strftime(date_format)  # return in the same format as the input

assert  get_future_date("01/07/2017", 1) == "02/07/2017"
```

Comment: ... And if you insist on rolling your own, the sane way forward is to use a simple linear time representation internally; the Unix epoch is a common example of such a canonical form.

Comment: @nath thank you for your advice. How I can use the datetime module using my code? can you please show me an example??

Comment: updated with an example which I think is close to your use case